# UIScrollView contentsize property

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I've a UIScrollView - 590 x 650
I've 2 UIImages in the scroll view with dimensions : 620 x 450
So, I set the contentsize and properties thus :

```
    self.scroller.minimumZoomScale=0.5;
    self.scroller.maximumZoomScale=6.0;
    self.scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1350, 950);// EDIT : 1350 because 620 + 620 
    //950 because 450 + 450 and 50 extra

    self.scroller.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0,0.0,44.0,0.0);
    self.scroller.scrollIndicatorInsets=UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0,0.0,44.0,0.0);

    self.scroller.delegate=self;
```

But when I try to run and scroll, only half/partial of the second image is displayed and the scroll bounces back, even when I pull the scroll all the way to display the end of the second image.

what am i doing wrong here??
 Is my content size setting/assumption correct??

If this question is already answered please point me to it, as I couldn't find the correct explanation.

EDITS :
*.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIScrollView *scroller;
    UIImageView *varImage1;
    UILabel *lblStyle;
    BOOL isAlpha;
    UITextView *textView;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *varImage1;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblStyle;

- (IBAction)notesClick:(id)sender;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *notesClick;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;


@end
```

*.m file

```
// calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [scroller frame].size.width  / [varImage1 frame].size.width;
    [scroller setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [scroller setZoomScale:minimumScale];
    scroller.contentSize= CGSizeMake(960,1170);

    scroller.delegate=self;
```

Image size is 1170x960
UIImage view size is : 1170x960 (width x height) picture set form IB and property set to scale to fit.

scroll view size is 590 x 650 (width x height)

object hierarchy :

[image]

Initial view on load : *NOTE : Even thought image is partially displayed, I can't scroll to the right and see the rest of the image.
[image]

After i zoom out the image, I can scroll even if the image is only partially being displayed
[image]

Comment: your images width is 620 so 620+620= 1240 not 1200
So please set content size
self.scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1350, 950);

Comment: What you're saying is correct. But that doesn't help anyway in answering the query. The UIImage still bounces back when I scroll vertically and doesn't show the second image completely.

Comment: @Vinu, Have you checked the frame for UIScrollView? Is it outside it's superview by any chance?

Comment: @ACB : Yes I have checked it. The placement of the left top corner of the UIScrollView is at 0,0. So no problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Would you show us the code, where you create and add the images?

Also a safe and general way would be the following:

```
CGSize contentSize = CGSizeZero;
for(UIView *view in self.scroller.subviews) {
  contentSize.height = MAX(contentSize.height, view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height);
  contentSize.width  = MAX(contentSize.width, view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.size.width);
}
CGFloat border = 50;
contentSize.height += border;
contentSize.width  += border;
self.scroller.contentSize = contentSize;
```

It will just find the lowest and most right position of any view in the scrollView and use it as the contentSize.

Comment: I added the image from the IB.

Comment: And you made sure, that the imageViews are subviews of the scrollView? What are the exact imageView frames? Why do you set all the other properties in code, if you are using interfaceBuilder. You can do it there. Is the IBOutlet `self.scroller` connected correctly?

Comment: Can contentSize be set from IB?? I read that only this has to be set in code, and hence I used the code to set the value. I made an outlet for scroller and connected properly and i am sure its working fine cause I have written the code for zooming and it works fine, so the outlet is also assigned and connected properly. Image view, I've added that in the scroll view in the IB, so I think it is right. Can we check it any other way?/

Comment: Please log the `frame` of the scrollView and both imageViews to the console and show it to us. Also log the final contentSize. After everything has been setup. Are you doing anything else with self.scroller?

Comment: sorry, I have chnged the contents a little, but the problem is still the same.